# How to Stop "Security Information for server.domain.com" Emails from Dedicated Server

Tags: linux, webserver, root, dedicated-server

Ever since I added a Reverse DNS record and a Hostname to our Linux dedicated server, we have been getting weekly emails from the server with the following content. We get these emails for each of our domains hosted on the server.

*server.mydomain.com : Jan 3 00:00:03 : anotherdomain : problem with default entries ; TTY=unknown; PWD=/var/www/vhosts/anotherdomain/.composer; USER=root;*

How do I prevent these emails?

[I tried a fix here on this site](https://superuser.com/questions/1086152/sudo-sending-annoying-alerts-issue-with-defaults-entries) but that didn't work because we don't have the nsswitch.conf file on our server. We have a similar file but it doesn't have the "sudoers:        files sss" content anywhere in it.

Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: “I tried a fix here on this site” - What fix? edit question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound - sorry, just added the hyperlink.